# Pygame Overlays

Tags: python, overlay, pygame

Okay, so I want to make an overlay screen.

So whenever the keypress is <kbd>p</kbd>  then the screen pauses and a screen pops up saying 
: "Press 'q' to quit or 'c' to continue,"
something like that.

Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is using a submodule, then to create a new loop for `blit()`-ing to the screen and event handling for this pause menu.

*(This is methodology only; this is how I work my projects.)*

**Update: 13/12/11**

The following excerpt of code is from the "parent" module. This is just the loop section of code. What you're looking for is the line `button.doAction(screen)`, which basically tells PyGame to execute the applicable submodule (not important; you just need to call the "child" function as you would normally).

```
while mainRunning:

    # --- Event Catching & Handling ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Quit PyGame safely upon exit
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainRunning = False

        # Make the buttons do actions
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for button in menuList:
                X = button.getXPos()
                Y = button.getYPos()
                if X[0] < mousePos[0] < X[1] and Y[0] < mousePos[1] < Y [1]:
                    button.doAction(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

So if we say that the function we wanted was `playGame.levelChoose()` - remember, this is [submodule].[function] - then the loop in the "child" would be:

```
def levelChoose(screen, playerData, playerName):
    levelChooseRunning = True

    while levelChooseRunning:
        # --- Event Catching & Handling ---
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Quit PyGame safely upon exit
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                levelMenuRunning = False

    pygame.display.flip()
```

(Of course, much code has been ommitted from these examples; if you'd like to pick apart the full files, they're [over here on GitHub](https://github.com/Crashdown/S-kuru))

Let me know if there's more questions, because this probably just confused you some more...